# applescript - move every file into its parent folder, but skipping existing files if they already exist

Tags: applescript

I have this script to choose a folder and then move the contents of the subfolders into it.

```
tell application "Finder"
    set top_folder to (choose folder)
    repeat with this_folder in (get folders of top_folder)
        move every item of this_folder to top_folder
    end repeat
end tell
```

What do I have to do in order to skip moving individual files if the same named file already exists in the top folder, but to continue across all files where it is still possible to move?

Comment: Doesn’t just appending `without replacing` at the end of the `move` line what you expect?